# Next.js favorite list best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js application with redux and a node.js Rest-API. You can view items and as often you can store favorites.

Now the view component of the items and the favorites is obviously the same.

I have now two options how I can do it and I want to ask you what is best practice with next.js:

1.Option:
Have two routes. One called "search" and one called "favorites".

Pros:

- Clean approach as everything is clearly separated from the root

Cons:

- Have to remove full DOM and add full DOM just to show favorites - which is essentially the exact same view

2.Option: One route called "search" with a prop for the section

Cons:

- Unclean IMO since I need to add a prop to many components

Pro:

- For me seems to be way faster

Redux store is organized the following:

```
{
  search:{
     results:[],
     total:0,
  },
  favorites:{
     results:[],
     total:0,
  }
}
```

Comment: For the second option, what kind of extra props would you need to add to the item components?

Comment: Also, are the routes you're talking about API routes or are they page routes?

Comment: They are page routes :) API is also different but response format is the same. It would be one extra prop but in the component itself roughly 30-40 different lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide a concrete answer to this question. Do you want one page for users to browse items, allowing them to filter by which ones they've favorited, or do you want one page for searching items regardless of which ones they have favorited and a separate page for finding favorites? This doesn't seem like a best practices problem, it's totally your choice. That said, I would probably prefer option 1 because that is how most applications do it. The fact that it is slow is weird—next.js tends to be very good about preloading. Give your page(s) a try in production mode—often Next.js is just slow to build them in development mode and the real page your users will face will be much faster.